# Reading two questions in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

I am making a levelling system for my bot so I wanted to figure out if there is a way to read two messages at the same time in discord.py?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to do that in the `on_message` event. It is possible to fetch more than one message if you have the id of the message and channel (`await channel.fetch_message(message_id)`).